# Is there a formula to work out how much the fabric of spacetime bends?

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, curvature

From my knowledge, a big mass (planet star etc) can bend the fabric of [spacetime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spacetime). Is there a formula that we can use to work out how much it bends?

Comment: See this answer on the Riemann curvature tensor https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/81113/whats-the-idea-behind-the-riemann-curvature-tensor

Answer (score 10):

It's not really a fabric, but anyway: yes, that formula is the [Einstein field equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_field_equations),

$$G^{\mu\nu} = \frac{8\pi G}{c^4} T^{\mu\nu}$$

Here $T^{\mu\nu}$ is the [stress-energy-momentum tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stress-energy_tensor), a collection of 10 numbers which describe the contents of space, and $G^{\mu\nu}$ is the [Einstein tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_tensor), a function of the [metric tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_tensor), which is a collection of 10 numbers that describe the "shape" of spacetime. Whatever quantity you would like to use (for example, the [scalar curvature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar_curvature)) to characterize the amount by which spacetime is "bent," you can calculate it from the metric tensor.